# SQL ORDER conditionally by column plus secondary column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case-when

I need to do an sql order by which covers a few cases...

I first need to order by a column expiry (epoch string), where this is greater than now or it is empty (non-expiring).

So expired records (those where expiry is less than now) will always come after the non-expired records.

Then within each of these cases, there needs to be a secondary search which is alphabetical.

tTABLE
id
name
expiry
active

My attempt so far:

```
select * from `tTABLE` WHERE `active`='1' 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN `expiry` > 1571410101 THEN 1
CASE WHEN `expiry` = '' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END,`expiry`
DESC
```

Comment: `expiry > 1571410101` , `expiry = ' '` is `expiry` column datatype is  `INT` datatype, or a string (`CHAR`/`VARCHAR`) datatype..  the datatype usage mixing seams odd here..

Comment: Run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tTABLE` ... And also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Remove the second `CASE` keyword. See [CASE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `tTABLE` t
WHERE  active = 1  
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN expiry > unixtime() 
               THEN 1   -- explicit future expires first
               WHEN expiry IS NULL
               THEN 2   -- no expires second
               ELSE 3
          END),
         name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this will work in MySql, but in **Oracle** the following SQL works:

```
SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN expiry > 1571410101 THEN 1
           WHEN expiry = '' THEN 2 
           ELSE 3 
      END exp
FROM tTABLE 
WHERE active = '1' 
ORDER BY exp DESC
```

I think the same will also work for MySql.

Comment: I tried that on Oracle and it works perfectly. I have found MySQL more strict than Oracle as a matter of fact. I mentioned Oracle because i was trying to give an idea of how the query could be structured.